# Order API + Payment with multiple line items creating wrong financial trxn record?

Tags: financial-types

Say I have two price fields, thumbtacks at $1/unit and ketchup at $20/unit (it's very good ketchup). Suppose they each have a different financial type, such as "Office" and "Condiments".

If I use the order api to create a contribution where you've bought one of each this looks fine. I get correct looking records in civicrm_line_item etc. The problem is when I record the payment. It properly records two items in civicrm_financial_item corresponding to the line items, but then in civicrm_entity_financial_trxn, it properly creates two records, but the entity_id for both of them points to the same entry in civicrm_financial_item. This then shows up in the UI on the contribution as "Condiments, Condiments" for the payment instead of "Office, Condiments".

When I record the same contribution from the start using the UI and the price set, it has entity_id pointing to the separate items, as I'd expect, and in the UI shows "Office, Condiments" for the payment.

The code looks something like this:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Order', 'create', [
  'contact_id' => 17,
  'financial_type_id' => 'Donation', // this seems irrelevant
  'receive_date' => date('YmdHis'),
  'contribution_status_id' => 'Pending',  // this is required according to the docs - the payment below completes it
  'line_items' => [
    [
      'params' => [],
      'line_item' => [
        [
          'label' => 'line 1',
          'qty' => 1,
          'unit_price' => '1',
          'line_total' => '1',
          'financial_type_id' => 22, // Office
          'price_field_id' => 12, // this seems almost irrelevant - using "1" has the same effect but then oddly doesn't show the line item breakdown when viewing the contribution
        ],
        // It doesn't seem to make a difference if I put the 2nd line item here or as a separate array in the outer array.
        // It's the payment part that is creating the wrong entity_id.
        [
          'label' => 'line 2',
          'qty' => 1,
          'unit_price' => '20',
          'line_total' => '20',
          'financial_type_id' => 23, // Condiments
          'price_field_id' => 13,
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
  'api.Payment.create' => ['total_amount' => 21],
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this old issue and PR

https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/58#issuecomment-289561525

you want to specify the price_field_value_id or else CiviCRM will try and be clever and guess one for you and will often get it wrong. I think it's using the same mechanism it uses when you specify values for a payment page without using a real price set - i.e. it access a hidden price set that it uses for the purpose.

Comment: Ah yes price_field_value_id seems to be what's missing. Thanks.